# What does the setting, "Omit code cell output when saving this notebook" mean?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am curious what the setting that says, "Omit code cell output when saving this notebook"

What exactly does that do?

Is it meant only for me?

So If I want to be in private mode will other users be able to turn my private mode off for example?

Answer (score 1):

That setting discards code cell outputs when saving the document.

So, if you have a code cell that contains `print ('x')`, execute it, and save, the `print ('x')` will be saved, but the rendered output `x` will be dropped.

A typical use of private outputs is to work with outputs that you don't wish to be saved in the history of the notebook.

Comment: I just realized today that google will log every single output of the notebook. Everything that we print and do on google colab is in the google server

Answer (score 0):

If you check the box then console/terminal/notebook output will not be visible when u share it.

#### Omit conclusion

If you planning to share or make notebook public, then check the box as it will result in a cleaner notebook and better user experience

**Notebook with code omit checked**
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kl7124cI89-yn-Stio8GiLpJV0jec6Kt

**Notebook with code omit __not__ checked**
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WR0zGWTjiDUOo3FeHpFoVlTWndTeChf4